# Properties for two non - similar matrices

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

What are the properties that two non - similar matrices will never have in common. For example:  Two non- similar matrices can have same values for eigen values so it can't be that property. Does any such property exists?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://kom.aau.dk/~jakob/selPubl/papers1995/ijmest_1995.pdf)

Comment: Same Jordan canonical form.